# Resources for full stack JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, mean-stack

I'm currently a Force.com developer and soon making a shift to the JS stack in a new position (Specifically Backbone, node, mongoDB).

I've completed several tutorials to ease the transition (mainly from http://scotch.io/)
but i've always found that tutorials and real life work are different.

Can anybody recommend good resources (I'm a learn-by-doing kind of person) that would present a real life challenge and help be better prepared for the challenges ahead?

Thanks

Comment: Your new team in your new position is using vanilla backbone or a framework like marionette?

Comment: They are using vanilla backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty hard to top Addy Osmani's (free) "Developing Backbone Applications":

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

This post is also very useful:

http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-backbone-js-completely/

Both of these resources go way beyond a typical tutorial.

Comment: Thanks cs_stackX, i'll delve into those. any good recommendations on node?

Comment: You're welcome. The same blog has a great walkthrough on node:http://javascriptissexy.com/learn-node-js-completely-and-with-confidence/ I'd also really recommend the codeschool.com course on node - though you have to subscribe.